# Is it possible to do `git clone --depth=1 <repository>` with libgit2?

Tags: git, libgit2

I want to do a quick clone without getting all the `.git` history. Is this possible to do with [libgit2](https://libgit2.org)?

I found [this issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/3058) but I am not sure if this sparse checkout they reference is

same as running `git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2`.

Comment: The issue you linked to is not about sparse checkout but about shallow clone with `--depth`. The issue is still open. The linked PR https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/6396 is still not merged. The bottom line: not implemented yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible! The libgit2 git_clone function takes [git_clone_options](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_clone_options) as an argument. One of the members of that struct is [git_fetch_options](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_fetch_options) which takes a depth parameter.

Note that to mimic `git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2` you will also need to fetch only the history for a single branch. This is achieved by passing your own callback via [remote_cb](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_clone_options).